# How to stop computer from entering sleep under "Critical Battery Trigger Met" misidentification?

Tags: windows-10, battery, sleep, windows-11, lenovo-laptop

I'm using a Lenovo Laptop, Windows 10.

**Update 15/2/2023: just today I upgrade to Windows 11, the same problem still persists (!)**

Recently I think the battery cell is not fully functioning, and system occasionally triggers the `Event 524, Critical Battery Trigger Met` and subsequently, the `Event 42,The system is entering sleep.`, even though the laptop is connected to the power source AND the battery is more than 95% charged.

Obviously, the system is misreporting the battery condition, and hence resulted in the above trigger, and then subsequently, the sleep event. This is very annoying because it disrupts the rhythm of my work.

How to stop the system from entering the sleep mode if the `Event 524, Critical Battery Trigger Met` is (mis)reported, and ***despite*** (potential) battery fault?

**Some asked:** how do you know that this is a misreporting, and not because the battery is really dying? My answer:

1. It's simple. Right before the machine goes to sleep, the battery is still more than 95% charged.
2. Does that really matter if the battery is dying? I am connecting the laptop to a power supply. So even if the battery dies the laptop should still have power supply, right?

Comment: What makes you think it's being misreported rather than accurately telling you your battery has reached the end of its useful life?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I know that it's a misreporting because the battery right before the sleep is more than 95% charged

Comment: That isn't conclusive proof, it's not even good anecdotal evidence. Read https://www.howtogeek.com/217010/how-to-generate-a-battery-health-report-on-windows-8-or-windows-10/ & tell us the result.

Comment: @Tetsujin, even if the battery is dying, my computer *shouldn't* go to sleep because it is plugged into the power cable.

Comment: @Tetsujin, so the question is not-- what to do if my battery is faulty ( or how to know if it's faulty), the question is , as per mentioned, *How to stop the system from entering the sleep mode* despite possible battery fault

Comment: I think this has turned into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Graviton - What is the make and model of the machine in question? Have you checked for a BIOS firmware update yet? If you take out battery and keep it out and then reboot it while the battery is not in it, does the issue occur still? Please note that just because a batter reads 95% charged does not mean it will not drain down quickly if the battery is old. Batteries are typically only guaranteed from manufacturer no more than 3 years so if it's older than 3 years, measure accordingly with a voltmeter, etc. or replace with a good known and see if it continues.

Comment: You're not answering the questions asked of you; you are just adding argument & opinion. There's nothing more anyone can do to triage.

Comment: I had this too (once), and I too don't see why shut down a laptop that's connected to AC... For me the event in question itself says that IsAcOnline=1, there have been no previous power-related events (I'd expect a low battery event logged?), the laptop (HP ProBook 430 G4) is just a couple years old, the battery report is uninformative containing "-"s in the last week's period...

Comment: @Graviton, have you tried applying the changes in Pim's answer? Do you have new information to share?

Comment: I'm late to the party, but to all commenters:  I dealt with this exact same issue, on my Lenovo laptop.  I replaced my battery and got exact same issues.  There's likely faulty hardware somewhere in the laptop that causes the battery to be misread.  I've just now tried setting the critical battery action to see if that fixes it.

Comment: same (annoying) issue Lenovo X1 Extreme 1st Gen Type 20MF.

Comment: Same issue on a Lenovo X1 Extreme 20QV

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe this can help.
Press Windows key and type: Edit power plan
In this menu go to: Change advanced power settings
In the next menu, all the way at the bottom there is Battery. In here you can define the Critical Battery Action for plugged in, for you this could be: do nothing.

Hope this helps.

Pim.

Comment: Why is this down president? Seems to me useful enough

Answer (score 4):

Running the following command as admin will set the `Critical Battery Action` for `On battery` to `Do nothing`. After setting this programmatically the `Do nothing` option should be available in the GUI dropdown for `Plugged in`.

```
powercfg -setdcvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_BATTERY BATACTIONCRIT 0
```

Comment: i'd NOT set that for On Battery, but for On Power.

Comment: But if you do not set it for Battery, OP's system will hibernate or shutdown randomly when the battery can be still half or even completely full. The point is that these events happen randomly. If you set a notification for critical battery level, you'll have gotten a notification for low battery already, so the next notification implies it's time to shutdown or find a power source. Leaving it up to the user still seems better than having your laptop shut off randomly at whatever battery level it feels like.

Comment: My theory is that older UPS systems will tend to start with a lower voltage when switching from the mains to battery power. Windows misstakes this for low battery and will immediately take action. I agree, this should not be set on a laptop but on a desktop/server that is expected to stay on 24/7? I recommend setting the "Do Nothing" if your blackouts will be less than the life of your battery and you have sufficient backups. Or buy a new UPS.

Comment: I have a desktop PC/server connected to an APC SMT1500 UPC and it often goes to sleep due to a random mistaken 524 battery event. This solution looks like exactly what I needed to get Windows to stop responding to this event. It was a poor assumption to remove 'Nothing' as a GUI choice out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue occurred when I changed my power mode settings(System > Power & Battery) to 'Best Performance' in Windows 11 installed on the laptop. My system has a gpu and two fans running all the time. I never faced this issue when my power mode settings is set to 'Best Power Efficiency'. My laptop doesn't even sleeps even when I remove the charger as it still has battery left but occasionally shuts down with same 'Critical Battery Trigger Met' when set on performance mode.

Edit: Critical battery level is set at 2%.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I found the solution for this. My computer kept doing this at 86% charge and mine had to do with a setting on the power plan. When I went to the "Edit Power Plan" Menu, then navigated to "Advanced Power Settings", then "Battery" I found that the Critical Battery Level had been set to 86%. This means that my computer would shut down when the battery went below that. All I did at this point was to restore defaults for the plan and it adjusted to 5%. However, if you have other custom settings for the power plan that you would not like to lose, then you can adjust the critical battery level setting manually to whatever percentage you like. The solution to the annoying problem was so straightforward that I made an account just to share this.

[image: Adjust Critical Level to 5%]